# Javascript Webcam not showing for iPhone browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webcam

I am working on this web app project that needs a video display of the webcam that is ongoing when the web app startup. Although for Apple device, I get a blank black screen.

`

```
const constraints = {
  video: true
};

const video = document.querySelector('video');
// Older browsers might not implement mediaDevices at all, so we set an empty object first
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

// Some browsers partially implement mediaDevices. We can't just assign an object
// with getUserMedia as it would overwrite existing properties.
// Here, we will just add the getUserMedia property if it's missing.
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {

    // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
    var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
    // to keep a consistent interface
    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
    }

    // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
  then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});
```

`

Here is the code. In conclusion, I would want this code to work on apple devices.

I tried looking if this was compatibility issue or security issue but nothing.

Comment: Did you play video? You may want to do that with `<video autoplay muted playsinline></video>` Which version of Safari  on iOS did you try?
Your code seems to work fine for me at https://berry-mint-icon.glitch.me/

Comment: Appreciate it fam, it is working now on both safari and Chrome on ios after I added the "autoplay muted playsinline".

Comment: Are you able to post a jsfiddle example of the working solution?